# ¿Se puede hacer un quicksort de manera descendente?

Tags: c#

Alguien podría orientarme sobre si se puede hacer que un QuickSort ordene de manera descendente? Que parte del código cambia? Unos compañeros me comentaron que se puede modificando los operadores relacionales, lo intenté y no funcionó.

```
private void QSort(int[] Arreglo, int Izquierdo, int Derecho)
    {
        int Pivote = Arreglo[(Izquierdo + Derecho) / 2];
        int i = Izquierdo;
        int d = Derecho;
        bool Bandera = true;
        do
        {
            Bandera = false;
            while (Arreglo[i] < Pivote)
            {
                i++;
            }
            while (Arreglo[d] > Pivote)
            {
                d = d - 1;
            }
            if (i <= d)
            {
                int Auxiliar;
                Auxiliar = Arreglo[i];
                Arreglo[i] = Arreglo[d];
                Arreglo[d] = Auxiliar;
                i = i + 1;
                d = d - 1;
                Bandera = true;
            }
        } while (i <= d && Bandera == true);
        if (Izquierdo < d)
        {
            QSort(Arreglo, Izquierdo, d);
        }
        if (i < Derecho)
        {
            QSort(Arreglo, d + 1, Derecho);
        }
        return;

    }
```

Espero puedan ayudarme u orientarme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En realidad es muy sencillo. Debes invertir los operadores que usas en los bucles `while`, de tal manera que:

```
while (Arreglo[i] < Pivote)
{
    i++;
}
while (Arreglo[d] > Pivote)
{
    d = d - 1;
}
```

pasa a ser:

```
while (Arreglo[i] > Pivote)
{
    i++;
}
while (Arreglo[d] < Pivote)
{
    d = d - 1;
}
```

Otra opción sería dejar el algoritmo como está, y después de la ordenación invertir el resultado (con `Array.Reverse` por ejemplo).